# C# - What Can I Do With This XML?

Tags: c#, xml

Actually I am kind a new at C# and I am trying to make a basic program for friendfeed for learn.

But I have a problem.

I can use C# library of friendfeed but it's old. For API V2 I have to work  without library.

So I decide to do it without lib.

I use WebRequest first and I am getting .xml file always. ( I am saving it as string, you can see in code. )

I am just asking, what can I do know, how can I get informations inside a XML file.

Can you help me?
Thank You.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class feed { }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = "semihmasat";

            WebRequest ffreq = WebRequest.Create("http://friendfeed-api.com/v2/feed/" + username + "?format=xml");

            WebResponse ffresp = ffreq.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)ffresp).StatusDescription);
            Stream stream = ffresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string respfinal = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? What information do you want? Have you tried an XmlDocument?

Comment: Check out [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx) namespace that has plenty of classes to help with parsing and retrieving data from xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also retrieve XML Data using Dataset.
Just write the code

```
Dataset ds = new Dataset();
ds.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(respfinal )));
```

And get the data in tables and do whatever you required.